# How to format Autocomplete output on Standard Address field

Tags: address, autocomplete

I have the autocomplete on standard address fields enabled which helps users enter new addresses with autocomplete (powered by Google).
The output is standard and currently autofill the country field with the full name of the country:
[image]

Is it possible to format this output? We have a validation rule that only allows international 2-digit country codes and would mean the user would need to manually update "Switzerland" to "CH" to be able to save.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt it's possible, but you should check with Salesforce support.  Also, have you considered using the State/Country Picklist feature?  Although that has its own set of headaches.

Comment: Underneath the hood it probably stores the field as a 2- or 3-digit code. Anyway, it's possible to modify the record on save via a before save trigger. That runs prior to a validation rule.

Comment: @DavidCheng 
Indeed, with 248 countries, it's a bit of a longer list, plus, using the address lookup would still be preferred as it auto-populates all address fields and ensures no erroneous/non-existent addresses are entered.

Comment: Thanks, @identigral! Not a bad idea. Was hoping for something OOTB but a flow could work too.